# Gitolite cannot push changes to a repo I made

Tags: git, ubuntu, gitolite

I have managed to setup gitolite on my server and I want push my app into it. So I am doing via:

```
git push amazon master
```

And I get the following response:

```
W access for home/git/repositories/webtags DENIED to git-admin
(Or there may be no repository at the given path. Did you spell it correctly?)
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

My gitolite config is

```
repo    gitolite-admin
        RW+     =   git-admin

repo    testing
        RW+     =   @all

repo webtags
    RW+ = pc_magas git-admin
```

And my remotes are:

```
amazon  mygitserver:/home/git/repositories/webtags.git (fetch)
amazon  mygitserver:/home/git/repositories/webtags.git (push)
openshift   ssh://57364a4c2d5271f0f500007b@webtag-pcmagas.rhcloud.com/~/git/webtag.git/ (fetch)
openshift   ssh://57364a4c2d5271f0f500007b@webtag-pcmagas.rhcloud.com/~/git/webtag.git/ (push)
origin  git@github.com:pc-magas/webtags.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:pc-magas/webtags.git (push)
```

Note that mygitserver is an alias for my server configured in .ssh/config:

```
Host mygitserver
Hostname ec2-52-30-197-137.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
IdentityFile ~/id_rsa.pub
User git
```

Do you know how to push on webtags repo.

Note: Both pc_magas git-admin have my keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pushing using a full path for a repo: `/home/git/repositories/webtags.git`
This is one of the ["bypassing gitolite" issues](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#ybpfail).

If you want gitolite to refer to its managed webtags.git repo, the url should be:

```
amazon  mygitserver:webtags.git (fetch)
amazon  mygitserver:webtags.git (push)
```

Meaning:

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git set-url amazon mygitserver:webtags.git
```

Then gitolite would look for the actual `/home/git/repositories/webtags.git`.